Send request to specific Cloud Run revision
I am making a post request to my Cloud Run app.
The current revision is serving 100% of traffic.
There are some old revisions which are currently serving 0% of traffic. Is it possible to route my request to one of these older revisions?
from google_cloud_utilities import get_gcp_identity_token
import requests

identity_token = get_gcp_identity_token(cloud_run_url)

headers = {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "Authorization": f"Bearer {identity_token}"
        }

response = requests.post(f"{cloud_run_url}/predict", json={"data": data_for_prediction}, headers=headers)


I saw in the web UI in the tab REVISION that there is a Revision tag you can set and the description says: To invoke a specific revision without changing traffic, assign a tag to the revision to get a dedicated URL for this revision.

Checked it out and it works pretty well actually. Thanks!

By adding revision tags you can give a revision a dedicated url:
gcloud run deploy ..... --no-traffic --tag staging
This revision then gets deployed with a url of https://staging--{original-url.run.app} and gets none of the traffic sent to the normal url.
